# How many cycles $A$ and $B$ can form this cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, cyclic-groups

How many cycles $A$ and $B$ can form this cycle:

$AB=(axyguimjrcwk)(bvqphsleofzt)(d)(n)$

I can see that $A$ and $B$ must share the cycle $(dn)$, and I believe due to ordering, both $A$ and $B$ must contain the same $24$ cycle each. So there should be only $1$ possible solution for $A$ and $B$. Is this right?

Comment: Could also be (something)(d)(n) for both

Comment: @DanUznanski true, but that something cannot be different can it?

Comment: It's different from (something)(dn) for both.

Comment: @DanUznanski So we have three solutions?

Comment: No, shouldn't be odd, unless you know you can pull that 2-cycle out in another way.  You basically have, all solutions for generating A'B' = (axyguimjrcwk)(bvqphsleofzt), and then for each of those, you can glom on (dn) or (d)(n)

Comment: @DanUznanski Okay, what if it were two 10 cycles and two 3 cycles? I can't get a good feel for these problems

Comment: It's still a bigger number.  consider... I could have (abcdef) on two things and that comes up (ace)(bdf)... but so does (aec)(bfd)^2 come up with that.  Or I could have (ace)(b)(d)(f) and (a)(c)(e)(bdf)

Comment: I don't know enough about permutation cycles to give a real answer here; I'm just filling in obvious holes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a permutation with a cycle of length $n$, then that cycle can be created by two other permutations $A$ and $B$ with cycles that live within those $n$ elements, as long as those two permutations can be themselves created by composing a particular length-$n$ cyclic permutation $P$ with itself some number of times $a$ and $b$ (including $n$ itself!), so $A=P^a$ and $B=P^b$, and $\gcd (a+b, n)=1$.  Your particular cycle is then $P^{a+b}$.

For instance, $(aie)(bjf)(ckg)(dlh)\times(adgj)(behk)(cfil)=(lkjihgfedcba)$; for $P=(abcdefghijkl)$, this is $P^8P^3=P^{11}\left(=P^{-1}\right)$

Similarly, if you have a permutation with $m$ cycles of length $n$, you can create this with two other cycles the same way, using a $P$ of length $mn$, and $\gcd(a+b,mn)=m$.

Finally, two permutation hunks that work on disjoint piles of elements can be combined in a single permutation hunk without a problem.

So, for your case, you have several options here: you can consider the two $12$-cycles as independent (so you're looking at two disjoint $12$-length permutations) or together (so you're looking at a $24$-length permutation); similarly, your two $1$-length permutations can be considered also a single $2$-length permutation, but they don't have to be.